# Dynamic generated iframe does not return its name and not identify iframe into DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have created one application where I am generating multiple nested iframes dynamically. In my structure, I have one iframe name as "list" along with same value to ID attribute. I get name as **" "**, In chrome when I tried to check its name as mentioned below:
**"parent.content0.list"** OR **parent.frames['content0'].frames['list']**

Only I get its name when I use index of its iframe like below
**"parent.content0.frames[0]"** OR **parent.frames['content0'].frames[0]**

All my iframes have name and Id attribute with same value.

Also, in chrome and Mozilla I get iframe instead of window object when i try below line of code on debugger:
**parent.frames['content0'].frames['list']**
but index path give window object
**parent.frames['content0'].frames[0]**

Check attached screen shot for more clarification. [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3neNg.jpg)

Let me know if you need any other details.

Don't know why iframe with index 0 have this issue in my code. All other iframes and index iframes are accessible and return correct value.

Because of this my form target is also not working as expected because my form has same iframe name as target.

Can anyone please help me to understand this behavior?

**Note:** Standalone code gives me correct name but dynamically created iframe[0] create an issue.

Comment: Yes we sure need more details and that's your code! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then create a **mcve** and edit your post and share it with us.

Comment: Thanks @EhsanT for your reply.

Comment: I will not be able to post my code here as everything is dynamic. Static code work fine as my expectation but not dynamic one. Both dynamic and static code are same DOM structure.

Comment: OK, as you wish. But we can not help you unless we have a **mcve**. We can not guess on the air what is going on in your code!